# Spring boot azure active directory multiple client-id

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot app that use azure active directory with front-end authentication [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter#authenticate-in-frontend) the microsoft page that I used. 
This app is the back-end and I would use for many front-end apps. 
How can I set in application.properties all different valid client-id for every front-end apps?

Comment: Were you able to make it work?